# How to re-download unauthenticated packages

Tags: apt, package-management, security, encryption, authentication

I live in Egypt. we have a country specific server here. I used to download everything from there. but when I got to download `encryptfs`, synaptic said the package could not be authenticated, so I changed the apt mirror to default ubuntu server and the packages could now be authenticated.

Due to the fact that we live in a country with mass surveillance and no laws to protect privacy or human rights, I have been thinking that maybe backdoors were placed in the unauthenticated package. so I have decided to re-download all the unsigned packages from the main ubuntu server, however this doesn't seem to be addressed anywhere.

So, in this regard, how to re-install packages?

Answer (score 1):

You can download and reinstall all packages using `--reinstall`:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall package1 package2 package3
```

But, make sure you cleared your cache before. Use

```
sudo apt-get clean
```

to clean the cache. Because, if a package is present in cache, `apt` won't re-download it.

Of course, the best way is [nuke the system from orbit](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/24195/27973) and start anew to assure the maximun security.

Comment: Are you suggesting to reinstall all installed packages? But if there are cached packages, those will not get updated packages

Comment: @AnwarShah how do you expect the packages to be unmodified? If there's a single hostile package all bets are off.

Comment: I think, you should also suggest OP to clear the cache before. and a way to generate a list of all installed packages would be nice